# difference between "teacher's monitoring" and "teacher monitoring"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

What is the difference between "teacher's monitoring in classroom learning activities" and "teacher monitoring in classroom learning activities?

Answer (score 1):

The genitive *'s* indicates that in the case of *teacher's monitoring*, the monitoring “belongs to” the teacher: the teacher does the monitoring.

*Teacher monitoring* can mean two things: monitoring *by* the teacher or monitoring *of* the teacher. 
It is ambiguous without further context, because it is actually not uncommon to monitor teachers during their work, but they can also monitor the students. Both meanings make sense, so we need more context.

As Araucaria noted, there is of course the possibility of the *'s* being a verb instead of a genitive: *The teacher's monitoring* can be a complete sentence.

Similarly, the second form could appear as *I saw the teacher monitoring*, where *monitoring* can be a verb (I saw the teachers as they were monitoring) or a noun (I saw the monitoring that was done by the teacher — or I saw the monitoring of the teachers).

Answer (score 0):

Denotatively, they're the same. But the attributive *teacher monitoring* is abstract and would be more likely to appear in a jargon-riddled document where the human element is taken out of the equation.

P.S. If someone were to nitpick, they could say that *teacher's monitoring* implies a single teacher, whereas *teacher monitoring* might involve more than one teacher. In the latter, teachers are a fungible resource; in the former, individuals.

Comment: Unless it'd *why the teacher's monitoring*, though.